# connecting to cassandra from PHP

Tags: php, pdo, cassandra

I have found lots of questions on here and other sites about what php libraries to use for connecting to cassandra but most of the questions are 1 or more years old.

I have also found lots of different libraries for connecting to cassandra but most of those have not been committed to for over 2 years.

The PDO php library https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-pdo seems to be the one most talked about but again this has had 0 changes since 2012.

So my question is what are people using and why?

Ive also seen this http://evseevnn.github.io/php-cassandra-binary which at first glance to me looks pretty promasing but it is really new and iam worried it may not be supported in the long term as appears to be the case with lots of others.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's the full list:

[Simple Cassie](https://code.google.com/p/simpletools-php/) - SimpleCassie is entirely stand-alone package which wrap itself around Thrift libs
*This Library hasn't had any commits in a while*.

[Pandra](https://github.com/mjpearson/Pandra) - Pandra is a light-weight PHP based CRUD layer for the Cassandra distributed datastore. *Seems inactive since early 2012*

[PHPCassa](https://github.com/thobbs/phpcassa) - PHPcassa is a PHP client library for Apache Cassandra. *Very active, I'd recommend this library since one of the DataStax developers is maintaining it.*

[Cassandra PHP Client Library](https://github.com/kallaspriit/Cassandra-PHP-Client-Library/commits/master) - Cassandra PHP Client Library allows for managing and querying your Cassandra cluster. *Inactive since late 2013*

[CQL | PHP](https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-pdo/) - A CQL (Cassandra Query Language) driver for PHP using PDO.

[CQLSÍ](https://github.com/cataloniaframework/cqlsi_v1_stable) - A simple interface, a wrapper, for working with CQL from PHP without Thrift. *Last activity was early 2014*

[Orange-OpenSource/YACassandraPDO](https://github.com/Orange-OpenSource/YACassandraPDO) - PDO driver for Cassandra CQL. *Also highly active, last commit was today.*

[PHP Library for Cassandra](http://evseevnn.github.io/php-cassandra-binary/) - PHP library for use Cassandra database via a binary protocol. *This is the library you listed, highly active.*

[php-cassandra](https://github.com/aparkhomenko/php-cassandra/commits/master) - A PHP driver for Cassandra.Works exclusively with CQL3 and Cassandra's binary protocol. *Very recent commits, but the library itself is very new*

Based on this list it'd say your prime choices are PHPCassa which has the advantage of being highly active, Orange-OpenSource/YACassandraPDO which is a mature and active project but as stated support for cassandra-2.0 is experimental and 2.1 isn't mentioned at all, or the other two projects which are less mature but recent and active.

Comment: Am i missing something with phpcassa? https://github.com/thobbs/phpcassa/issues/142 says no support for 2.0 and there gas not been a commit in 6 months, there has only been 5 commits this year.

Comment: @AlistairPrestidge Ah, reading through too many libraries at once. Your right. I'll update the answer but it looks like your best bet is the library you were thinking about initially.

Comment: That is what I was half expecting. I am currently chatting with someone from datastax about drivers they may support in the future and or which one they would suggest for now. The one they suggest to use at the moment is PHPCassa but they did admit that this does not work with 2.0 or newer. Ill update this when I have an answer of some sort.

Comment: I use of YACassandraPDO with cassandra 2.0 it's work not bad but it don't work with 2.1

Answer (score 3):

Better late than never.

[Datastax](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/php-driver-beta-release) have finally come up their [php-cassandra driver](https://github.com/datastax/php-driver)

It is still beta but you can rely on them for further updates.

I was using Orange-OpenSource/YACassandraPDO for the past 6months. Fairly good.
Might replace this with datastax driver in future.